# Shiny: conditionally build UI

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building a Shiny dashboard to show a large amount of data. People access the dashboard through a separate login page (non-Shiny) that sits in front, at which point a JWT is generated and put in a cookie. I've managed to read in the cookie in Shiny and parse the data, saving the token in a variable called `userPermissions`. Now, however, **I'd like to show/hide tabs in the dashboard depending on the user permissions.**

For example: I have data on both managers and assistants. I want to show the manager data to any user with `userPermissions == 'manager'`, and the assistant data to anyone with `userPermissions == assistant`.

I thought the best way would be to use `conditionalPanel()` – here's a (simplified) reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)

# UI file 
ui <- fluidPage(

    # JS to read cookie -- simplified to just return value!
    tags$head(tags$script(
      HTML('
            Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("goReadTheCookie", function (message) {
              Shiny.onInputChange("cookie", "manager");
            })
           ')
    )

    # Title 
    ,titlePanel('Test')

    # Navbar
    ,navbarPage(
      id="navbar"
      ,conditionalPanel(condition = "userPermissions() == 'manager'",
                        mainPanel(textOutput('Manager data')))
      ,conditionalPanel(condition = "userPermissions() == 'assistant'",
                        mainPanel(textOutput('Assistant data')))
    )

)) 


# Server file 
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session){

    ## Grab permissions from Cookie
    # Prepare output
    userPermissions <- reactiveVal("")

    # Tell JS to return cookie
    session$sendCustomMessage(type="goReadTheCookie", message=list(name="cookie_name"))

    # Listen for cookie
    observeEvent(input$cookie,{   
          ## -- Bunch of code omitted for sake of brevity -- ##
          userPermissions("manager")
    })

})

# Run app
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

The problem with this code is that, in a browser console, I get the error `Can't find variable: userPermissions`.

I guess what's going on here is that the entire `ui` is executed, before JS can grab and return the cookie. What would be the best way to solve this?

Or, maybe I'm going about this the wrong way. I obviously need to verify the cookie server-side (i.e., in `R`) not to divulge the secret; and preferably this check, and the hiding/showing is completed at the very start of the Shiny application (`userPermissions` won't change during the session). Maybe there's a different (& better) solution to get to that point?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: It depends also on how securely you want those panels to be 'hidden' from other users. If determined a user without permission could simply toggle off the `display:none` in chrome console and view the content still

Answer (score 1):

In the end I found that the function `appendTab` does exactly what I was looking for. This needs to be run in `server.R` though, within the function to look for the cookie (otherwise `userPermissions` indeed doesn't exist). I could then do:

```
appendTab("navbar"  # the id of the navigation bar created in ui.R
          ,tabPanel("tab name"
                    ,mainPanel(...))
)
```

where `tabPanel(...)` could be anything you'd normally put in `ui.R`.

The added benefit here is that hidden tabs are also not available in the HTML source, as they're never even passed from the server to the client!